# Installer not installing Outlook Add-in

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook-addin

Whenever I build the Add-in from Visual studio(2017 Community version),the add-in gets loaded in Outlook(2016) and functions as expected.But when I remove the add-in from Outlook and then try to install it using the .msi installer file the add-in doesn't gets loaded in the Outlook.
Anyone having any idea about this?

Comment: Specify what type of addin are you talking about and how are you trying to install it.

Comment: I am making a VSTO add-in for Outlook 2016 using Visual Studio installer available under File >New > Project > Other Project types > Visual Studos Installer > SetUp project. I created a setup projectin Solution Explorer,Added the primary Output file of the Project and built it. I got a .msi file. it shows setup wizard .Completes it but does nothing.